# Hide Navigation Bar in React Native Modal

Tags: react-native

I want to hide the bottom Navigation Bar in React Native Modal.

I have a full-screen mode, set in Main.java, it's workin everywhere, but when I want to open a Modal, the bottom navigation bar just become visible. Can I turn this funciton off?
I need a Modal withouth Navigation Bar.

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION 
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN 
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Once my solution:

```
// the screen you try to hide the tab
hideTab(){
        let navigation = this.props.navigation.dangerouslyGetParent();
        const setParamsAction = navigation.setParams({
          showTabBar: false 
        });
        navigation.dispatch(setParamsAction);
    }
```

navigation config:

```
C2CStack.navigationOptions = ({navigation})=>{
  //console.log('===========>C2C navigation options:');
  //console.log(navigation);

  return {
    tabBarLabel: '法币',
    tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
      <TabBarIcon
        focused={focused}
        name='c2c'
      />
    ),
    tabBarVisible:navigation.state.index==0&&((navigation.state.params && navigation.state.params.showTabBar) !== false)
  }
};
```

The ugly thing is to determine the params belonging to which property and in which level.

Comment: Yeah.. I want to create a dynamic modal (with this component: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/modal), not a page with react-navigate.
And I dont want to specify where I want to hide the tab, I want a full-screen app, withouth the default Navigation bar (Back button, Home Screen, Running apps) in adnroid